# Error on my SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL query and I am getting an error.

```
SELECT 
table1.id as id,
CONCAT( table2.first_name , ' ' , table2.last_name ) as name,
table2.country_code as country_code,
(select table3.id from table3 where table3.user_id = table1.id AND table3.description NOT LIKE '%SOMETEXTHERE%' LIMIT 1) as trans_id,
table4.important as important,
table1.status as status
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON eid = table2.id
LEFT JOIN table4 ON table4.ewallet_transaction_id = trans_id
ORDER BY transaction_date desc;
```

The error is: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'trans_id' in 'on clause'`

But the trans_id does exist.

Note: I also try other alias for 'trans_id' like 'transaction_id'

This might be an easy question but I just cant figure it out. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is `trans_id` in any of your tables...?

Comment: where is the alias of table where trans_id exist ?

Comment: @agold it does not, it is an alias

Comment: @raveenanigam alias for (select table3.id from table3 where table3.user_id = table1.id AND table3.description NOT LIKE '%SOMETEXTHERE%' LIMIT 1) as trans_id,

Comment: You can not use an alias from select statement in the on clause.

Comment: @Jens Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: You can use the 'longhand'

Answer (score 0):

**Because your mix join syntax**
To allow the join to be processed, group the first two tables explicitly with parentheses so that the operands for the ON clause are (t1,t2) and t3:

SELECT * FROM (t1, t2) JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);

Alternatively, avoid the use of the comma operator and use JOIN instead:

SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `JOIN` FOR `table3` too, this way

```
SELECT 
    table1.id as id,
    CONCAT( table2.first_name , ' ' , table2.last_name ) as name,
    table2.country_code as country_code,
    table31.trans_id as trans_id,
    table4.important as important,
    table1.status as status
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN (select id as trans_id, user_id from table3 where table3.description NOT LIKE '%SOMETEXTHERE%' GROUP BY 1) table31 ON table1.id=table31.user_id
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON eid = table2.id
    LEFT JOIN table4 ON table4.ewallet_transaction_id = table31.trans_id
ORDER BY transaction_date desc;
```